# Ran into syntax error when trying to organize/sort data in VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm trying to sort some information in particular cells in Excel. Here's what I have so far.

```
Public Sub SplitAddress()


    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim strCurrentName As String
    Dim strPreviousName As String
    Dim intDuplicate As Integer
    Dim docGuestList As Worksheet
    Dim tblguests As Range

    Set docGuestList = Application.Workbooks("T10-EX-E2D.xls").Worksheets("Consultants")
    Set tblguests = docGuestList.Cells("B2:B17")

    tblguests.Sort excludeheader:=True, _
    fieldnumber:=2, sortfieldtype:=wdSortFieldAlphanumeric, _
    sortorder:=wdSortOrderAscending, _
    fieldnumber2:=3, _
    sortfieldtype2:=wdSortFieldAlphanumeric _
    sortorder2:=wdSortOrderAscending
```

But I'm getting a syntax error for the `sortorder2:=wdSortOrderAscending` linw. I have no idea why... :( Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma in the parameters list, after `wdSortFieldAlphanumeric`:

```
fieldnumber2:=3, _
sortfieldtype2:=wdSortFieldAlphanumeric, _
sortorder2:=wdSortOrderAscending
```

Comment: Allow me to rage. Thanks :)